# tensorflow: applying calculated weights on a single mnist image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I am going through a machine learning tutorial using tensorflow and the mnist dataset. Let's say I trained my model and tested it, so the model returns the weights W as an array of shape (784, 10) and the bias b as an array of shape (10,). Now if I pick a single image from the mnist test dataset

```
img=mnist.test.images[1,:]
```

which is of shape (784,), I would assume to calculate the prediction for this image by calculating

W * img + b like this:

```
tf.matmul(W,img) + b
```

but this won't work due to rank issues. Instead I tried calculating W * img as follows:

```
M=[W[:,0].dot(img), W[:,1].dot(img), W[:,2].dot(img), ..., W[:,9].dot(img)]
```

and then getting the final result adding the bias: M+b. This works fine but there has to be an easier way instead of using the dot product multiple times (in other models there might be much more than 10 labels).

For the technical problem the learning and testing code should not be of much relevance but here is the code so you can reconstruct the output

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import trange
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Import data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("datasets/MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Create a Session object, initialize all variables
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Train
for _ in trange(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

# Test trained model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print('Test accuracy: {0}'.format(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})))

#The output can be extracted using
W = sess.run(W)
b = sess.run(b) 

sess.close()
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? Why would your model return weight W with the shape (784,10)? Do you want to say your model input an image with the shape (784,) and outputs the image's label with the shape (10,)?

Comment: I thought referring to the mnist dataset would make that clear. But yes, you are right. The mnist dataset contains images of size  28 x 28 = 784 of the ten digits (0...9). The learning and testing code should not be of much relevance here, I think.

Comment: The weight `W` is still confusing. How do you expect to create a model with that? Maybe you can check out this guy's repository for a similar approach: https://github.com/snehalvartak/MNIST/blob/master/FullyConnectedNet.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question seems to be tf.einsum.
Let's pick the 100th image of the mnist test data, which should be a 6:

```
img=np.asarray([mnist.test.images[100,:]]) #(a 28x28 image of a 6)
imgT=tf.constant(np.transpose(img)) #TensorShape([Dimension(784), Dimension(1)])
wT=tf.constant(np.transpose(W)) #TensorShape([Dimension(10), Dimension(784)])
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    R=sess.run(tf.einsum('ij,jk->ki', wT, imgT)+b)
    sess.close
np.argmax(R) #=6
```

Using tf.constant the arrays img and W are converted to tensors.
Instead of using tf.einsum, there might be also a way using tf.tensordot but I could not find out what to use as the axes argument to get the same result.